# htaccess redirect 301 для ЧПУ URL

Tags: .htaccess

Есть сайт, настроены ЧПУ ссылки
но сайт индексировался раньше, чем были сделаны чпу. поэтому остались дубли со старыми URL
По ним можно перейти.
Задача сделать redirect 301 .
Как я пытался это сделать/
Вот код , который стоит, который я собсвтенно модифицирую

```
RewriteRule cat([0-9]+)-.*  index.php?categoryID=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule prod([0-9]+)-(.*)$ index.php?productID=$1&$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule orderA$ index.php?orderA=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule orderAQ$ index.php?orderAQ=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule admin$ admin.php [L,QSA]
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page_not_found=yes
```

Моя логика, создаю правило, если робот переходит по ссылке типа не чпу
делать rewriteRul R=301

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} index.php?categoryID=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ cat%1? [R=301,L]
```

Аналогично для productID.
Это один из вариантов , которых я пробывал. Перечитал много постов по данной теме, так же терминологию на оф.сайте
Но в итоге пока не получилось.
Уважаемые знатоки, прошу помочь или направить меня в нужное русло. Буду благодарен за любую информацию, которая мне поможет разорбаться.
Спасибо за потраченное время.